# Date not equals to two dates

Tags: sql-server, date-comparison, select-query

I have got data from table. There is one `datetime` field in table. Field name is `createdon`

In select query I pass two datetime parameters Now I want all data from table where `createdon` field is not equals to these two date time parameters.

Comment: Please add your statement. It seems as you are passing the parameters in wrong format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A literal interpretation.

```
SELECT *
  FROM TBL
 WHERE createdon NOT IN (@date1, @date2);
```